# How to draw a triangle in QTableView cell corner to show the model data can be selected from a list?

Tags: python, delegates, pyqt, qtableview

The default behaviour for editing a cell is double clicking it, but i want to show to the user that, there is a list they can select from, ( some of my columns have only one value, and is not editable ) , so i opened persistent editor, but it's too slow if there are too many rows.

so i turned to reimplementing the mousePressEvent and show the combobox when user right click on the cell, but without any visual cue to tell them which cell can be right clicked on. ( i know maybe i can change bg color of that cell )

but can i achieve something like this? drawing a black triangle at the lower right color of the cell to indicate that it can be right clicked on ?

like this image from excel ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [QStyleItemDelegate](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html), something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class StyledItemDelegateTriangle(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StyledItemDelegateTriangle, self).__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(StyledItemDelegateTriangle, self).paint(painter, option, index)

        polygonTriangle = QtGui.QPolygon(3)
        polygonTriangle.setPoint(0, QtCore.QPoint(option.rect.x()+5, option.rect.y()))
        polygonTriangle.setPoint(1, QtCore.QPoint(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y()))
        polygonTriangle.setPoint(2, QtCore.QPoint(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y()+5))

        painter.save()
        painter.setRenderHint(painter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.darkGreen))) 
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.darkGreen)))
        painter.drawPolygon(polygonTriangle)
        painter.restore()

class MyWindow(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.styledItemDelegateTriangle = StyledItemDelegateTriangle(self)

        self.setItemDelegate(self.styledItemDelegateTriangle)
        self.setRowCount(2)
        self.setColumnCount(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.resize(333, 111)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```